# Add numbers when Inserting MYSQL with a select

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I want to do a thing that i don't know if it's possible.
I want to do an insert from a select but first adding a prefix in one of the values but its not working, if someones can give me an advice would be great.

This is a little example of what im doing:

```
CREATE TABLE ppl(
firstname VARCHAR(30),
lastname VARCHAR(30),
machineid VARCHAR(30)
)

CREATE TABLE machine (
id VARCHAR(30),
machinename VARCHAR(30)
)

CREATE TABLE repuestos (
id VARCHAR(30) ,
firstname VARCHAR(30) ,
lastname VARCHAR(30),
)

INSERT INTO repuestos (id, firstname, lastname)
values ((CONCAT('000000000', SELECT ID FROM MAQUINA)), (SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM PPL WHERE NAME = (SELECT ID FROM MAQUINA) )  )
```

Can anyone advise me?

Thanks

Comment: Try a INSERT with SELECT instead of with VALUES. I.e. something like `INSERT INTO repuestos (id, firstname, lastname) SELECT ...  FROM MAQUINA ... `.

Comment: And how can I concatenate the '000000000' to the insert?

Comment: In the SELECT list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
INSERT INTO repuestos (id, firstname, lastname)
SELECT CONCAT('000000000',M.ID),
        FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM PPL P
JOIN MAQUINA M ON M.ID = P.MACHINEID
```